# How to make sure that my application is using Proxy server and not my IP address in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, phantomjs

I am using Selenium with PhantomJS browser. I have set up proxy as below:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "../Drivers/phantomjs.exe");

ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy=hostname:port");
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-auth=username:password");
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-type=http");
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);

driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

My application is running fine. But how to validate if my application is using the proxy that I have set up?

Comment: Stop your proxy, staart the app and try loading any web page. If it fails to load - you are using proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before running your main script, make request to http://api.ipify.org/ that shows client's current IP and check in the code if it's your IP or the proxy IP.

Comment: Thanks. This solution helps.

Comment: @Abhilash If this solution was helpful please consider accepting it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can using [fiddler](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/Proxy) to [setup a proxy server](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureJavaApp) on your local, after that, change your selenium proxy configuration to proxy you have setup. Let's run your app, if your app going throw proxy then fiddler will catch it.